# Naming slices of numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large matrix that represents.. say a Rubik's cube.

```
>>cube

>>[[-1, -1, -1,  1,  2,  3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  4,  5,  6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  7,  8,  9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  8,  1,  8],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  0,  7,  7,  6,  9,  6,  8,  1,  0],
   [ 7,  8,  9,  6,  9,  7,  6,  6,  9,  0,  1,  7],
   [-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  8,  8,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  8,  0,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  7,  1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  8,  1,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

I have sliced it into parts that represent the faces.

```
top_f   = cube[0:3,3:6]
botm_f  = cube[6:9,3:6]

back_f  = cube[3:6,9:12]
front_f = cube[3:6,3:6]
left_f  = cube[3:6,0:3]
right_f = cube[3:6,6:9]
```

I want to now assign a modified matrix to the left face.

```
left_f = numpyp.rot90(left_f, k=3)
```

But this does not change the values in the parent matrix `cube`.
I understand this is because the newly generated matrix is being assigned to the variable `left_f` and so the reference to the sub-slice `cube[3:6,0:3]` is lost.

I could just resort to replacing it directly.

```
cube[3:6,0:3] = numpyp.rot90(left_f, k=3)
```

But that wouldn't be very readable. 
How do I assign a new matrix to a named slice of another matrix in a pythonic way?

Comment: What about `cube[3:6,0:3] = left_f` after `left_f = numpyp.rot90(left_f, k=3)` ? I'd say that your code is pythonic enough. When working with matrices, you're bound to work with many indices.

Comment: BTW, isn't `cube` too big? The last 3 rows aren't used.

Comment: @eric-duminil Yes that would do the trick but its not ideal. Suppose later I change left_f slice to some other part of the matrix say `cube[3:6,1:4]` then I would have to hunt throughout the code to replace those parts. I wish to keep the explicit use of the indexes to minimum.

Comment: You might need another data structure. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500221/how-would-you-represent-a-rubiks-cube-in-code) might help you.

Comment: The cube is purposefully three rows bigger, I am actually using it to keep another representation of the back_f so that I can easily roll the columns for representing moves. I have changed the matrix in the question to show this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into those other data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign your slices to a variable:

```
left_face = slice(3, 6), slice(0, 3)
cube[left_face] = np.rot90(cube[left_face], k=3)
```